# Facebook share inside facebook showing og:title & og:image of the iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe

I am placing an iFrame (xx.com) at the client website (yy.com), the iFrame has a facebook share that should redirect to the client site (yy.com). The problem is with the og:image & og:title as I am placing them in xx.com bcz I have no access to yy.com. The share is not displaying the image and title I am placing in xx.com. Is there a way to do so?

the code in xx as follows:

```
<head>
<meta property="og:url" content="yy.com" />
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:image" content="image-path" />
</head>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ar_AR/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxapp-id";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="yy.com" data-type="button_count"></div>
```

The code in yy.com is as follows:

```
<iframe width="950" height="600" frameborder="0" src="http://xx.com/path-to-file"></iframe>
```

Comment: let's see if I got it right. You are framing xx.com inside yy.com, or the other way around? Anyhow, the framing site is what gets shared with the share button. I would consider the share dialogue `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=APP_ID&link=your_link&picture=some_pic&name=title&caption=caption&description=etc&redirect_uri=url_you_want`, etc. The share dialogue still works.I am not sure if it's going to stay, but I like it because with a simple `<a href></a>` you achieve what you want

Comment: yes I am framing xx.com inside yy.com. I need the share button that shows the number of shares

Comment: then my answer won't be of any help, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this as follows:

I redirect the share button to xx.com instead of yy.com having the title and the image url as a parameters in the URL and then inside xx.com I set the og:title and og:image according to the parameters passed and I redirect the user to yy.com

The share button in xx is as follows:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="xx.com?share_url=yy.com&title=the_title&image=the_image" data-type="button_count"></div>
```

The code for redirecting in xx is as follows:

```
<?php
$share_url = $_REQUEST['share_url'];
if(isset($share_url) && $share_url!=''){
$video_title = $_REQUEST['title'];
$video_image = $_REQUEST['image'];
?>  
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $video_title ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $video_image ?>" />   
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=<?php echo $share_url ?>" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```