# Facebook share from contained iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, facebook, iframe

I've got a page A that embeds a page B as an iframe. Both sitting on separate domains.

Page B has a one page Angular application and functionality to share a link card on Facebook.
The image on the link card depends on the information the user has entered in a form contained in the iframe, and there are 7 images the app will chose from.

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a share link card carrying the URL of page A (and linking to page A) and images and copy determined by the app contained in page B.

Any leads? Hope this is clear enough.

Cheers

Comment: Nobody, really? :(

Comment: About a year late, but have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303271/facebook-share-inside-facebook-showing-ogtitle-ogimage-of-the-iframe?s=3|0.5969)?